# How to block temporarily jquery mousewheel

Tags: jquery

I have a small animation of a home page and need to disable the mousewheel till it's done (which I manage to do with the jquery mousewheel plugin). My problem is that I can't figure out how to enable the mousewheel again after this animation.

```
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#header").position().top }, 3000).bind("mousewheel", function() {
return false;     });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess `.unbind("mousewheel")` would be the thing. So:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#header").position().top
}, 3000, function() {
    $(this).unbind("mousewheel");
}).bind("mousewheel", function () {
    return false;
});
```

The [`.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) lets you supply a callback function that will be called on completion of the animation, so within that function you can unbind your mousewheel handler.

(Note: if you're using jQuery version 1.7 or later it is generally recommended to use `.on()` and `.off()` rather than `.bind()` and `.unbind()`, though for this purpose they do the same thing.)